# Does Android support device-dependent implementation for third-party libraries?

Tags: java, android

I'm about to start working on a library for Android that will expose a custom video player (a wrapper around ExoPlayer to handle integration with our CMS, advertisements, analytics, etc)

Some of the underlying implementation details are going to change based on the specific device that the player is running on (Android Mobile vs Android TV). I planned on effectively building something like the following:

```
Main SDK
  |- MobilePlayer SDK
  |- TVPlayer SDK
  |- CMS API SDK
```

However if someone were to build a mobile app using this SDK, they would only utilize the "MobilePlayer" and "CMS API". The "TVPlayer" would be dead weight.

Therefore I'm interested in some means of conditionally linking and compiling only the implementation required for a specific device. If someone were to build an Android TV app using my SDK, I would like it to link the TVPlayer and not bloat the app with an unused MobilePlayer. Similarly if someone were to build an Android Mobile app using my SDK, I would like it to link the MobilePlayer and not bloat the app with an unused TVPlayer.

Is this possible? Would it require the creation of two separate SDKs ("Main-TV" and "Main-Mobile")? Do compiler directives exists to only import the implementation I want, or does the Java compiler support some form of tree shaking?

Note that what I'm looking for is effectively the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), but resolved at compile time and not at run time.

Comment: Usually libs will offer a shared "core" module along with a choice of other modules. Suppose your features all share the core logic, someone would depend on "sdk-core" and "sdk-tvplayer" if they only wanted the tv player stuff

Comment: What is in `Main SDK`? If it is just common stuff, shouldn't the dependencies here be inverted, with the player SDKs depending on the main SDK?

Comment: `Main SDK` was intended to be a single JAR file that you could include in your project that encapsulated both the `CMS API` and `XPlayer`. It doesn't add any functionality, but provides a single library that you can import into your project and start working (like how ExoPlayer provides `exoplayer` but also `exoplayer-core`, `exoplayer-hls`, `exoplayer-ui`, etc -- the `exoplayer` library is just a single JAR that includes all of the child libraries and allows you to include a single dependency and get all of the functionality)